# How to compare the contents of two .js files using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two .js files with several functions defined in them and I wish to compare the contents of these two files. Is there an npm package for such a comparison or any other way to do this?

Comment: What kind of content are you wanting to compare? Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: I can give you instructions and an example if you the files are just .txt files

Comment: simple text comparison, to see if any of the functions are changed or added

Comment: Seems like you just want to run a `diff`.  There are many developer tools packages that contain a diff tool that you can just run as a child_process.

Comment: I've got the solution by reading these comments, thanks.
I'll simply do a by-text search as it serves my purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to compare them as if they were 2 plain text files.
You could do something like this:

```
function readFile(name) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        fs.readFile(name,  function (err, data) {
            if (err) { reject(err); }
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
Promise.all(readFile('file1'), readFile('file2')).then(data => {
  var file1 = data[0];
  var file2 = data[1];
});
```